# Distance between a vertex from itself

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

In undirected graphs the distance between a vertex from itself is 0, what about directed graphs if there is no path with positive length? For example only one vertex

is it 0 too or $\infty$?

Comment: I'd still put $0$ in general, but this might be important to have some context on the purpose of the weights

Comment: Seems like a matter of definition.  For a single vertex it could be undefined.